# Interlacing two ordered sequences with constraints

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, order-theory

How many ways can we create a sequence of length $2n$ from $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{y_j\}_{j=1}^n$ so that  $x_1<x_2<\cdots <x_n$, 
 $\;y_1<y_2<\cdots <y_n$ and 
 $x_i<y_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$ ?

This question is related to the following
[enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666288/number-of-ways-to-interleave-two-ordered-sequences?noredirect=1&lq=1), but with an extra condition on the ordering between the two sequences.

Using the wordings in the original question: Suppose we have two finite, ordered sequences $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,\cdots,y_n)$. How many ways can we create a new sequence of length $2n$ from $x$ and $y$ so that the order of elements is preserved AND we have orderings $(x_i,y_i)$ for all $i$?

Comment: Are you preserving the orders of the sequences as in the original question?  Which conditions are you trying to insist upon and which properties are given?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. I've added a paragraph to try to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Catalan number.

If a's are left parentheses and b's are right parentheses, the condition translates into "there are less then i right parentheses to the left of the i-th left parenthesis".

e.g. For n = 3 we have

$(\ )(\ )(\ ),\ (\ )((\ )),\ ((\ ))(\ ),\ ((\ )(\ )),\ (((\ )))$ or

$a_1b_1a_2b_2a_3b_3,\ a_1b_1a_2a_3b_2b_3,\ a_1a_2b_1b_2a_3b_3, \ a_1a_2b_1a_3b_2b_3,\ a_1a_2a_3b_1b_2b_3$